# Return conditionally formatted sequential data by button

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sorting, conditional-statements

Need VBA to return ECRs >30 days with the "Location" the ECRs are in. When you hit the easy button. The Program needs to scan the Red cells and create an array and put array into another workbook.
[image]

Code so far:

```
Sub easy_button_2()
Dim rw As Long, c As Long, fast As String, X
fast = "Y"

With Workbooks("ECR Log w_fast.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet 3")

With Workbooks("ECR Log w_fast.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet 2")

    'clear any previous ECR #s/Location results
    rw = Application.Match("ECR #s", .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)), 0)
    With .Range(.Cells(rw + 24, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Resize(.Rows.Count, 2).Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
    End With
    'reset the Locations named range
    With .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(3, 1).End(xlDown))
        .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Name = "Locations"
    End With

    'cycle through the ECRs in Locations' column 1
    With .Range("Locations")
        For rw = 2 To .Rows.Count
            If .Cells(rw, 3) > 30 Or .Cells(rw, 2) = fast Then
                For c = 3 To .Columns.Count
                    If .Cells(rw, c).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
                            .Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(1, 2).Offset(1, 0) = _
                            Array(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, .Cells(1, c).Value2)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next c
            End If
       Next rw
    End With
End With
End With
```

'Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\MJ\Desktop\ECR Monitor.xlsm"
'ThisWorkbook.Activate
End Sub

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to help much until you edit your answer and post some code

Answer (score 2):

There are two different ways to determine the status of a conditional formatting rule directly from the observed cell color. You can use the [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx) as you've started to do or use the [Range.DisplayFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814.aspx) to check the .Interior.ColorIndex (you were filtering for **3**, not **255**).

> <sup>It seems that the **Locations** range could be expanded well beyond the seventh row. To localize it to a dynamically updated range, the defined name **Locations** will be redefined according to the cells expanding from A3.</sup>

**Method 1: AutoFilter method**

```
Sub easy_button_1()
    Dim rw As Long, c As Long, vr As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("sheet2")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False

        'clear any previous ECR #s/Location results
        rw = Application.Match("ECR #s", .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)), 0)
        With .Range(.Cells(rw + 3, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            .Resize(.Rows.Count, 2).Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
        End With

        'reset the Locations named range
        With .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(3, 1).End(xlDown))
            .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Name = "Locations"
        End With

        'AutoFilter the Locations named range
        With .Range("Locations")
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">30"
            For c = 3 To .Columns.Count
                '.AutoFilter Field:=c, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
                .AutoFilter Field:=c, Criteria1:=vbRed, Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
                If c > 3 Then
                    .AutoFilter Field:=c - 1, Criteria1:=vbGreen, Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
                    '.AutoFilter Field:=c - 1, Criteria1:=RGB(0, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
                End If
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0)
                    'only attempt to transfer values if there is something visible
                    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                        For Each vr In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                        'cycle through the visible rows
                        .Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(1, 2).Offset(1, 0) = _
                            Array(vr.Value2, .Cells(0, c).Value2)
                        Next vr
                    End If
                End With
                If c > 3 Then .AutoFilter Field:=c - 1
                .AutoFilter Field:=c
            Next c
            .AutoFilter Field:=2
        End With

        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Step through the above procedure with repetitive **F8** taps to watch the process work through.

**Method 2: Range.DisplayFormat property**

```
Sub easy_button_2()
    Dim rw As Long, c As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet2")

        'clear any previous ECR #s/Location results
        rw = Application.Match("ECR #s", .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)), 0)
        With .Range(.Cells(rw + 3, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            .Resize(.Rows.Count, 2).Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
        End With

        'reset the Locations named range
        With .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(3, 1).End(xlDown))
            .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Name = "Locations"
        End With

        'cycle through the ECRs in Locations' column 1
        With .Range("Locations")
            For rw = 2 To .Rows.Count
                If .Cells(rw, 2) > 30 Then
                    For c = 3 To .Columns.Count
                        If .Cells(rw, c).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
                            .Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(1, 2).Offset(1, 0) = _
                                Array(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, .Cells(1, c).Value2)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next c
                End If
            Next rw
        End With

    End With
End Sub
```

Step through the above procedure with repetitive **F8** taps to watch the process work through. Watch the values of *rw*  and *c* change as you cycle through the **Locations** named range.

> <sup>Note that both of the above rely on numerical color code constants of **vbRed** and **vbGreen**. If you are using colors with shades off of the primary RGB(255, 0, 0) and RGB(0, 255, 0) then you will have to make adjustments.</sup>

[image: filter_by_color]
                          <sup>*Filter by color*</sup>

Comment: btw, there should be at least one completely blank line between the **Locations** and the area below it for reporting the >30 reds.

Comment: The first time *rw* is used, it is the first match (relative row number) for **ECR #s** below row 4. It is is not matching then perhaps you don't have a **ECR #s** in column A below row 4. The second time it is used, it is cycling through the rows in **Locations** below the header. *c* cycles through the columns.

Comment: Hey Jeeped, When you get a chance please look at my comment. Sorry this is the last time I will bug you :)

Answer (score 0):

What if I wanted to return the values this program runs onto another worksheet or another workbook? Can I just reference the array in another workbook? Maybe declare the array as a variable to reference it?

Or do I have to put the array in another worksheet and reference to another workbook?

```
Sub easy_button_2()
Dim rw As Long, c As Long, fast As String
fast = "Y"
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Set ws3 = Workbooks("ECR Log w_fast.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet 3")
With Workbooks("ECR Log w_fast.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet 2")

    'clear any previous ECR #s/Location results
    rw = Application.Match("ECR #s", .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)), 0)
    With .Range(.Cells(rw + 100, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
         .Resize(.Rows.Count, 2).Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
    End With
    'reset the Locations named range
    With .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(3, 1).End(xlDown))
        .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Name = "Locations"
    End With

    'cycle through the ECRs in Locations' column 1
    With .Range("Locations")
        For rw = 2 To .Rows.Count
            If .Cells(rw, 3) > 30 Or .Cells(rw, 2) = fast Then
                For c = 3 To .Columns.Count
                    If .Cells(rw, c).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
                            ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(1, 2).Offset(1, 0) = _
                            Array(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, .Cells(1, c).Value2)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next c
            End If
       Next rw
    End With
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: The outer [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) doesn't appear to be doing anything. If you need to reference another worksheet, perhaps declare a variable like `Dim ws3 as worksheet` and set it with `Set ws3 = Workbooks("ECR Log w_fast.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet 3")`. You can then use it anywhere like `ws3.Cells(1, 2)` or `ws3.Range("A1").

Comment: Hi Jeeped. I managed to use your advice above and it worked! The results are now on the next worksheet (3). My last question is how do I clear and reset the values when it is on worksheet 3? Take a look at the code above I edited. Thanks Mike

Comment: Possibly something like `w3.cells(1, 1)currentregion.clearcontents`.